# Cross-Browser issues. Links not showing up in Safari, but works in Mozilla

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Here's the html:

```
   <ul id="header">
        <li><a href"#login">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li id="divide">|</li>
        <li><a href"#login">Login</a></li>
        <li id="divide">|</li>
        <li><a href"#profile">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And here's the corresponding css:

```
ul #header {
list-style-type:none;
}

ul > li {
display:inline;
float:right;
margin-right:2px;
margin-left:2px; 
}
```

The links don't show up in Safari... It just shows black text instead of blue links. Otherwise, it shows the same thing between browsers. This is a list of horizontal links separated by vertical lines.

Answer (score 4):

`<a href"#login">` should be `<a href="#login">` and the same for all the other links.